# Regexp to match a word, surrounded by word boundaries, which don't include forward slash

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to make PHP regex word boundary not match certain characters as word boundaries?

For example, when I run `/\btwo words\b/` RegExp on the following, I don't want any matches:

```
google.com/two words
stackoverflow.com/login?two words
yahoo.com/topics/99421231#$two words
```

However I **do** want matches for the following:

```
two words
one two words three
# two words
(two words)
.two words
!two words
```

PHP code: `preg_match("/\btwo words\b/", $text, $result);`

Comment: If you have specific PHP code you've tried, please include that in the question.. Also, what if *lazy dog* is a word pair within a string with a seemingly matching URL (e.g., one of your last three examples with a valid match as well)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround), listing what you want to exclude inside of a character class.

```
preg_match('~(?<![/?$])\btwo words\b~i', $text, $result);
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cU2jJ4/2)